# Every countable compact Hausdorff space is homeomorphic with a subset $([0,1],|\cdot|)$?

Tags: general-topology

Every countable compact Hausdorff space is homeomorphic with a subset $([0,1],|\cdot|)$ ?
How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

In fact every countable compact Hausdorff space is even homeomorphic to a subset of $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554372/infinite-compact-subset-of-mathbbq/554506#554506) to a (different) earlier question. You can find a proof of the Sierpiński-Mazurkiewicz theorem — the main ingredient in the construction — [here](https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/cantor-bendixson-rank-in-topology-sierpinski-mazurkiewicz-theorem/). (It’s also linked from the answer.)

The key point is that every countable compact Hausdorff space is homeomorphic to a countable compact ordinal $\omega^\alpha\cdot n+1$, where $\alpha<\omega_1$, $n\in\omega$, and the arithmetic is [ordinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic); the answer to which I linked shows that each of these can be embedded in $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$.