# Classification of compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}>|X|\geq \aleph_1$?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

On my own time, I've been curious/investigating some properties of compact Hausdorff spaces of cardinality $\aleph_{\alpha}$, for $\alpha \geq 0$ a particular ordinal. I am aware of the following results:

- A compact Hausdorff space without isolated points is uncountable (various proofs including [Munkres](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131816292) and the classic [diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_argument));
- Compact Hausdorff spaces which are finite or countably infinite are homeomorphic to $\omega^{\beta} \times n + 1$, where $\omega$ is [the first infinite ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), $n \geq 1$ is a finite positive ordinal, and $\beta \geq 0$ is an arbitrary countable ordinal ([Sierpinski-Mazurkiewicz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554372/infinite-compact-subset-of-mathbbq/554506#554506));
- A compact, uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ ([Cantor-Bendixson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set_property)).

My question is:
**What is known [in ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) regarding the shape/structure of uncountable compact Hausdorff spaces of cardinality $\kappa < 2^{\aleph_0}$?**
I'm particularly interested in the case of cardinality $\kappa = \aleph_1$.
Is there nothing that can be said to characterize compact spaces $X$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$, in the absence of [CH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), other than that the [successor ordinal spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Ordinals_as_topological_spaces) of cardinality $\aleph_1$ are compact?
In particular, I'm curious if there exists a known counterexample: a topological space $X$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$ which cannot be embedded in such a compact ordinal space.

Comment: Can the one point compactification of a discrete space of size $\aleph_1$ be embedded in an ordinal? Doesn't look like it to me

Comment: I edited the title to make it clear that you're interested in spaces of cardinality less than the continuum.

Comment: The first bullet point can be improved to: a non-empty, compact Hausdorff space without isolated points has cardinality $\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$. Hence, a compact Hausdorff space $X$ with $|X| < 2^{\aleph_0}$ is scattered (i.e., each non-empty subset has an isolated point).

Comment: The third bullet can be improved to: Every compact, first-countable space is countable or has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, see Handbook of set-theoretic topology (1984), Ch. 1, 7.20.

Comment: In the second bullet it should read as $\omega^\beta \cdot n + 1$ instead of "$\times$", and the space must have at least two points.

Comment: By a construction somewhat similar to the Cantor Set, we have: The cardinal of a non-empty locally-compact Hausdorff space with NO isolated points is at least $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Alessandro Codenotti's assumption, let $X$ be the one-point compactification of an uncountable, discrete space. Then $X$ cannot be embedded into a linearly ordered space:

Assume on the contrary. Then, by compactness, there is a linear order $\le$ on $X$, such that the order topology is the given topology.
For $x \in X$ define $X^{\le x} = \{y \in X: y \le x \}$.
Analogously, $X^{< x} = \{y \in X: y < x \}$.
Let $\infty$ be the non-isolated point of $X$. W.l.o.g., $X^{\le\infty} $ is uncountable.
If $x \in X^{< \infty}$, then $X^{\le x}$ is finite, hence the map
$X^{< \infty} \rightarrow \mathbb N, x \mapsto |X^{\le x}|$ is well-defined and easily seen to be strictly monotonically, in particular one-to-one. Contradiction!

**Update** 
Here is a very different example:
$X := (\omega_1 +1) \times (\omega +1)$, both factors with the order topology. Since they are compact, $X$ is compact, $|X| = \aleph_1$.
Since $X$ contains the non-normal deleted Tychonoff plank, it cannot be embedded into any linearly ordered topological space.